# HELM vs K8s Operators

Tags: kubernetes, operators, kubernetes-helm

I'm planning to create a simple K8s operator which creates a deployment and service. How is this different from doing with HELM? All articles are creating operators which deploys something. But my point is, we can do same with HELM. Why to complicate it with K8s Operators?

Comment: Operator manages entire lifecycle of the application, not just its installation. Eg: an operator may create clustered database and elect primary-replica nodes.

Comment: feel free to update the status of question if any of below answers your question

Answer (score 1):

First of all **Yes** you can create *Operator* with **Helm** for sure.

**Helm** is for **YAML** templating basically to deploy and manage resources.

> All articles are creating operators which deploys something.

Even if you will go with **Helm** it will **deploy Operator** for sure, that's what the meaning of **Operator** is. A **Deployment (Code/Logic running)** which **monitoring** the **Resources** in the cluster if required it will **create/update/delete** it.

You can use the [operator-sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/) to create the **Operator** and further write your own **CRD** and **CR** as per need with **Helm** **templating**.

**Update**

Main different is when you use **Helm** to deploy for example simple, **MongoDB** you will have **statefulset** running or a **service** which is a normal **deployment** you have done with **Helm**. There is **no** **operator** running you simply deployed resources with Helm.

Now suppose you have a requirement to scale **MongoDB** with adding new **Replicas** how you will do that ? Just scaling the Replicas of stateful set **3 -> 4** is not solution you have to run **pre/post** script **Data Volume replication**.

**Operator** comes into the picture here, you have deployed the Operator helm chart here so **Operator** Code is running as deployment. You create further Custom Resources with Config you are looking for in **MongoDB** and apply that changes. The operator will check that config and set the **Replicas**, **Volume** and **monitor** the **mongoDb** deployment.

Comment: Thank you Harsh for answering. My question was more of - whatever we are doing with operator, we are doing same with HELM. Example: deploying mongodb. Then why should we do it with Operator instead of HELM?

Comment: Got you question, Did you ever tried deploying mongoDB simple and mongo with Operator using HELM ? check updated answer.

Comment: When we scale mongo statefulset, the new pod will then be provisioned with a new persistent volume, which will be initialized with the same data as the existing volumes right?

Comment: Yes it will init with new volume but your data will sync to that replica mongo ? who will check and takecare there operator comes to picture, is pod failing have some issue it auto restart POD.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of minor differences between these two approaches.  The three big advantages I'd cite for using an operator are that it will be in a mainstream programming language; you manipulate Kubernetes objects as type-checked structures and not by writing out text that happens to be YAML; and you can do normal unit testing (Go/Kubebuilder provide a good setup for this).

| Capability | Operator | Helm chart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Language | Go (typically) | `text/template` language |
| Create Kubernetes objects | As structs | By writing out text that is YAML |
| Testing | Go `testing` package | Write your own |
| Permissions | Its own Role | The user's permissions |
| Pre-deploy inspection | No | `helm template` |
| Post-deploy modifications | No | Post-processing capability |
| In-cluster requirements | Controller must stay running | State kept in Secrets |
| Complex/staged deployments | Implement in controller code | Limited capabilities via hooks |
| History | Implement in controller code | Built in |
| Prepackaged dependencies | Vendor-provided operators | Community chart libraries |
| Multi-app deployments | New operator to produce CRs | Helmfile, Terraform, ... |
| Out-of-cluster resources | Implement in controller code | No |

A lot of these considerations matter more for large or complex applications.  If you can adapt the default Helm chart for a single Deployment, then it won't matter that you can't write unit tests for it or that it's in a niche language.  The various prepackaged charts are also convenient to use, for example to attach a common relational database to a service.

You can start asking questions like "can I create a cloud resource as part of my deployment process"; an operator could do that, Helm cannot.  People occasionally ask lifecycle questions like "can I delay creating my Deployment until my database is running"; an operator could do that, Helm cannot.  Both of these are more advanced capabilities and just a basic deployment wouldn't need it.

Comment: In a nushell, Helm is simpler and easier to use.

Comment: ...but an operator can do literally anything where Helm can only write out YAML manifests, and if you wind up writing a substantial amount of Helm code (not just YAML files with simple Go-template substitutions), it's much harder to test.